# DNS is not working

Tags: dns

When I am trying to `nslookup` the `www.google.com` from my server it is not getting resolved. But when I am providing DNS IP, after `nslookup` command it is getting resolved.

```
[root@XYZ ~]# nslookup www.google.com
Server:         XX.YY.ZZ.AA
Address:        XX.YY.ZZ.AA#DD

** server can't find www.google.com: NXDOMAIN

[root@nmsutnTRFL ~]# nslookup
> server DNS IP
Default server: DNSIP
Address: DNSIP#XX
>
>
> www.google.com
Server:         DNS IP
Address:        DNS IP#xx

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 216.58.196.100
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this? As due to this application running on my server not resolving the IP's.

Comment: Do you have DNS IP listed in /etc/resolv.conf?